# android screen orientation detect bug?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-orientation

I'm new to android, I encountered this problem while learning the basics.

I've searched for my problem in google and here but can't find similiar one.

My problem is I can't detect when the screen orientation changed to landscape.

Here's the code I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726657/how-to-detect-orientation-change-in-layout-in-android)

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("orientation landscape");
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("orientation potrait");
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "undefined", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("orientation undefined");
    }
}

    <activity android:name=".Hello2011Activity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@style/testem"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here's the log

```
07-27 16:19:11.935: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=18}
07-27 16:19:12.065: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=18}
07-27 16:19:12.305: INFO/System.out(1241): orientation potrait
07-27 16:19:15.485: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/1 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=18}
07-27 16:27:11.465: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=18}
07-27 16:27:11.665: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=18}
07-27 16:27:11.885: INFO/System.out(1241): orientation potrait
07-27 16:27:14.035: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/1 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=18}
07-27 16:27:20.401: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=18}
07-27 16:27:20.675: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=2/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=1 layout=18}
07-27 16:27:20.865: INFO/System.out(1241): orientation potrait
```

As you can see there's only notification for when I change the orientation changed from landscape to potrait and not vice versa.

I've tried avd 2.1update1 with api level 7 and avd 2.2 with api level 8.
OS is windows xp sp 3 with eclipse 3.6.2.

Is this a bug or there's something wrong with the code?

Comment: I just take a look, it look OK with your source.it seem strange behavior, could you please send you full source code to my email, very interesting issue :)

Comment: I've also tried the code. The method `onConfigurationChanged` is not executing in landscape mode.

Comment: @nguyendat I create a new project to test it, and it still don't work. Here's the project code http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=64677725252486745434

Comment: @Mudassir I thought I'm only one having this problem :)

Comment: android:screenOrientation="portrait" to activity is use for not make change of orientation

Comment: Of course, when the orientation is set to landsacpe one does not expect a configuration change in the orientation. _However_ when the screen is locked on certain phones and the lockscreen rotates, the underlying app rotates as well. The result is a restart of the activity if it cannot detect the orientation change.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem but using orientation|keyboardHidden didn't solve it. anyone has an idea?

EDIT:
After some trial and error, I found that this works for me:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: For reference/guidance to other users, I am linking to another stack answer which (probably) explains best why this code worked for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12226667/269876

Answer (score 0):

[activity-restart-on-rotation-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

[how-do-i-detect-screen-rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843809/how-do-i-detect-screen-rotation) and use `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to activity is use for not make change of orientation (this can use with the activity tag into the `AndroidManifest.xml`) like this

```
<activity android:name="testActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

(after using this the device will not make sense on change of the orientation)

Comment: I don't want to force screen orientation, I just want to detect if the orientation changed. But thanks for the info.

Anyway I already got my answer(see my post below) but I don't know how to close this thread.