# onConfigurationChanged problems

Tags: android, android-orientation

I need to change layout of my Android (4.1 API 16) application when orientation is changed.

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      setContentView(R.layout.main_2);
      System.out.println("Orientation changed!");
    }
```

Also I have added the next line to manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

I use Ctrl+F11 to change orientation. My screen rotates but layout stays the same and nothing is printed in LogCat. Feels like onConfigChanged event doesn't occur.

Where is my mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: In manifest where did you put android:configChanges="orientation" ?

Comment: <activity
            
            android:configChanges="orientation"

Comment: In which activity, you have override the methos **public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using **`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`**

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
>   also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
>   orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
>   orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
>   declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
>   must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
>   value. That is, you must decalare
>   **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"**. However, if your
>   application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always
>   handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change
>   does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or
>   higher device).

Source : [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Hence, also add **`"|screenSize" to configChanges`** if your application targets **API 13 and above.**

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your portrait orientation layout file is in layout/my_layout.xml

Place the layout you want to be used in the landscape mode in layout-land folder with the same layout file name. i.e. **layout-land/my_layout.xml**

**Do not add** android:configChanges="orientation" to the the manifest for that activity.

You do not need to explicitly change the layout. You **do not** need to override the onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) function

Answer (score 0):

try this one....

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```