# How can I detect screen rotation?

Tags: android, rotation

is it possible to detect screen rotation? I mean - rotation only, which is clearly distinguishable from activity initialization from another activity?

The onXxx methods seem not to be useful for this, I have tried adding/removing a `flag` from the `starting Intent` (the removing seems not to be reflected, on rotate the flag is there), and have tried adding **android:configChanges="orientation"** for the activity in the manifest, however the `onConfigurationChanged` method seems to be called every second rotation... wired.

I guess I am missing something... but haven't found clear solution in the other related threads.

Any ideas?

Comment: you mean like if it switches from landscape to portrait or vice versa?

Comment: isn't this thread the same? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843809/how-do-i-detect-screen-rotation

Comment: In the onConfigurationChanged Method you can detect which type of ConfigurationChanged occured, like the screen rotation.

Comment: try this also

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843809/how-do-i-detect-screen-rotation

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|screenLayout|navigation"/>
```

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    Log.d("tag", "config changed");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        Log.d("tag", "Portrait");
    else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        Log.d("tag", "Landscape");
    else
        Log.w("tag", "other: " + orientation);

    ....
}
```

try this link also

[How do I detect screen rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843809/how-do-i-detect-screen-rotation)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, I have tried it, before posting the question, and this does not work for me, no idea why, but the onConfigurationChanged is not called every time. It is called only when the orientation is becoming the same as the original (every second time).

Comment: where are you testing it? Can you post your code? Cause I tested it on a phone and it worked

Comment: I am testing it on the emulator and looking at the LogCat view. The code is 100% the same as posted above, without the orientation checks:
<code>android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"</code>
in manifest (only for this activity) and 
<code>@Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  
  Log.d(" - ", "onConfigChanged"); // TODO remove
 }
</code>
in the activity class...

Comment: Additional info: here is the output in LogCat:

`Activity first init:
08-01 10:50:11.920: DEBUG/-(279): onCreate
08-01 10:50:11.940: DEBUG/-(279): onStart

First rotation:
08-01 10:51:13.420: DEBUG/-(279): onPause
08-01 10:51:13.450: DEBUG/-(279): onCreate
08-01 10:51:13.510: DEBUG/-(279): onStart
08-01 10:51:13.510: DEBUG/-(279): onRestore

Second rotation:
08-01 10:52:37.970: DEBUG/-(279): onPause
08-01 10:52:37.980: DEBUG/-(279): onCreate
08-01 10:52:38.000: DEBUG/-(279): onStart
08-01 10:52:38.153: DEBUG/-(279): onConfigChanged`

Comment: jum.. that's why...For me, it doesn't work on the emulator but it does on a real phone. Maybe you should see if there is any kind of bug about it...

Comment: I found this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189 seems like there is a problem in the emulator

Answer (score 8):

Use onConfigurationChanged method to detect the screen rotation isn't good idea. Configuration Change in this activity wouldn't works correctly when user rotate the screen.

So I use this solution to solve this problem.

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String KEY_LAST_ORIENTATION = "last_orientation";
    private int lastOrientation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            lastOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        checkOrientationChanged();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        lastOrientation = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_LAST_ORIENTATION);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(KEY_LAST_ORIENTATION, lastOrientation);
    }

    private void checkOrientationChanged() {
        int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (currentOrientation != lastOrientation) {
            onScreenOrientationChanged(currentOrientation);
            lastOrientation = currentOrientation;
        }
    }

    public void onScreenOrientationChanged(int currentOrientation) {
        // Do something here when screen orientation changed
    }
}
```

But code still not good enough to use it in my project, so I applied this code to my own library (https://github.com/akexorcist/ScreenOrientationHelper).

```
compile 'com.akexorcist:screenorientationhelper:<latest_version>'
```

You can create base activity class like this

```
    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ScreenOrientationHelper.ScreenOrientationChangeListener {
    private ScreenOrientationHelper helper = new ScreenOrientationHelper(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        helper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        helper.setScreenOrientationChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        helper.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        helper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        helper.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScreenOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

    }
}
```

Then extend the activity with this base class

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onScreenOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        // Do something when screen orientation changed
    }
}
```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this?

in **onCreated** get the orientation of the phone:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
myOrientation = display.getOrientation();
```

then, override the method **onConfigurationChanged** and check if the orientation has changed:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    if(newConfig.orientation != myOrientation)
        Log.v(tag, "rotated");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Don't forget to add into the manifest `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the activity.