# Why Device rotation from potrait to portait doesn't destroy the activity?

Tags: android, screen-rotation

I want to do something whenever the device rotation changes, so I am doing that on onResume.But there is one scenario when I rotate the device from portrait to portrait, in this scenario it doesn't destroys the activity. Any Ideas why this happens and solutions will be greatly accepted.

Mainfest

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.components.main.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|density|screenLayout"
        android:label=""
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"/>
```

Comment: Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896243/how-can-i-detect-screen-rotation

Comment: when you say `onResume` do you mean `Activity.onResume()` or `Fragment.onResume()` ? Have you tried overriding `onConfigurationChanged(...)`?

Comment: Fragment onResume and yes i try overriding OnConfigChange