# Orientation Changed Event or Listener Android

Tags: android, android-orientation

Is there any event or listener which fires @ time of orientation changed?

or,
how to find out that the orientation of phone is changed?

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read up on [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

It explains the old way of doing handling stuff like orientation change.

Since `Fragments` was introduced, they have implemented a new way of doing it (similar to the old one) - but if you don't use `Fragments` it makes no sense using it.

Comment: actually problem with my app is... I am using viewpager and when the orientation change the detail fragment don't display the appropriate data... that is why i want to handle this kind of changes, do you have any idea for other alternative.

Comment: A vague question gives a vague answer - if you want a specific one, you need to ask a specific question. Maybe add some code to your question and tell us what is going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is a listener for this,

Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationListener.html

That is the class have a look through there.

Hope that helped.

Comment: The answer below would probably be your best bet :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use OrientationEventListener class instead !!
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are more interested in when an orientation change triggers a redisplay of the layout, you might want to check out this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener.html

"Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the layout bounds of a view changes due to layout processing."

Answer (score 0):

Since 180° rotation are not detected by onConfigurationChanged,

See better answer here:
[How do I detect screen rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843809/how-do-i-detect-screen-rotation)

Answer (score -1):

On some phones orentation change event fires before actual resize event. Do not recommend u to use orientation change event when u need to know when form is resized.

Just use $(window).resize(function(){ stuff to do })

If u need to have dynamic resize event and change it at some point u can use structure like that

```
function ResizeEventHandler (){
  var resizeEvent = function(){}

  this.ResizeEvent = function(value){
        if (value!=null) resizeEvent = value;               
        else return resizeEvent()
  }
}

var ResizeEventHandlerInstance = new ResizeEventHandler();

$(window).resize(function(){ ResizeEventHandlerInstance.ResizeEvent();   });

function YourDinamicalEventSetterFunction(){
    ResizeEventHandlerInstance.ResizeEvent(function(){
               alert('resized');
    });
}
```

basically when u need to change resize event -> change ResizeEventHandlerInstance... and you will not need to unbind event all the time when u want to change it

Comment: While your answer is complete, this question is tagged with [android] specifically and the solution you have provided is not an Android SDK solution but a WebView solution.  This answer just muddies the water.