# android: get width and height in other rotation

Tags: android, caching, orientation

I am rendering an image in a Fragment and using http caching on all image fetches. I'd like to anticipate the user switching orientation and fetch the other orientation while the user loads the initial orientation. I'm using `getView().getWidth()` and `getView().getHeight()` in the fragment. Is there a way to get the view's height and width in the orientation that the user is currently **not** on?

Comment: Give try to this that allow you to control the rotation event http://stackoverflow.com/a/11291621/5993599

Comment: Give try to this that allow you to control the rotation event http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843809/how-do-i-detect-screen-rotation/11291621#11291621

Comment: OrientationEventListener is only helpful once the orientation has changed. I'd like to know what the dimensions will be without actually rotating.